# Web application states

Tags: web-services, rest, session, web-applications

Rest is meant to be stateless. Client maintains application state and server maintains resource state. In statefull application where does that state is maintained? Is it maintained in session or in In-memory database or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

From the oracle documentation:

What is a Stateful Session Bean?

A stateful session bean is a session bean that maintains conversational state.

Stateful session beans are useful for conversational sessions, in which it is necessary to maintain state, such as instance variable values or transactional state, between method invocations. These session beans are mapped to a single client for the life of that client.

A stateful session bean maintains its state between method calls. Thus, there is one instance of a stateful session bean created for each client. Each stateful session bean contains an identity and a one-to-one mapping with an individual client.

When the container determines that it must remove a stateful session bean from memory (in order to release resources), the container maintains the bean's state by passivation (serializing the bean to disk). This is why the state that you passivate must be serializable. However, this information does not survive system failures. When the bean instance is requested again by its client, the container activates the previously passivated bean instance.

The type of state that is saved does not include resources. The container invokes the ejbPassivate method within the bean to provide the bean with a chance to clean up its resources, such as sockets held, database connections, and hash tables with static information. All these resources can be reallocated and re-created during the ejbActivate method.

https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13981_01/undejbs002.htm

Bare in mind the **"serializing the bean to disk"**, note that this is oracle's implementation and it does not mean that all implementations are done this way.

Comment: so I got the session part but again, does session exist in rest architecture style(stateless)? or is it only present in statefull one?

Comment: in a rest architecture you are not suppose to keep track of user session. you can make it happe, but speak from the angle of architecture this is wrong